# mod_rewrite dynamic flat links, wildcard directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to build an online store using dynamic php pages. Currently, .htaccess works with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^online_store/category/(.*)$ category?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My index.php is just built with a bunch of includes, so a flat link to browse a category would be:

```
domain.com/online_store/category/apparel
```

Index.php is including online_store.htm, which processes the URI properly.

What I'm trying to accomplish next is to add a rule for product URIs, which would tell index.php to include product.htm to process the given URI:

```
domain.com/online_store/category/apparel/t-shirt1
```

I thought it would be as easy as adding:

```
RewriteRule ^online_store/category/(.*)/(.*)$ product?uri=$2 [QSA,L]
```

But it doesn't work. Even my uneducated mind tells me that the previous rewrite rule for categories preempts this one since L is included - but when I remove it neither work. Can someone educate me on the proper way to process this? Logically, I need this to happen:

```
domain.com/online_store/category/(URI1)/(URI2) 
rewrite domain.com/category?uri=(URI1)
rewrite domain.com/product?uri=(URI2)
```

Final Edit - I decided to scrap the idea of nesting the product within the respective category, turns out I had issues with the way I was getting the URI using my php script. Here's the .htaccess that is working for me:

```
RewriteRule ^online_store/category/([^/]+)$ /category?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^online_store/product/([^/]+)$ /product?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It helped me come to a solution, thank you! I've updated the original post with what I ended up doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
RewriteRule ^online_store/category/[^/]+/(.*)$ category?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

it has to do with [greedy repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). Basically, the dot matches any character, including the slash(/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried what you recommend in a number of different ways with no positive result. Here's what my .htaccess looks like, is this what you meant?

RewriteRule ^online_store/category/(.*)$ category?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^online_store/category/[^/]+/(.*)$ product?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Sorry that format didn't turn out well. I've updated the original inquiry with what I'm intending on doing